# Make buttons fixed to top right of panel-title with bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I use bootstrap to display some panels. In the title bar of these panels I display a button for closing the panel. It looks fine until the text in the title bar is too long and the buttons are placed a row down.

Made a fiddle to illustrate

https://jsfiddle.net/fiddlejan/vt7tuj8b/

As you can see the cross icon is put next to the second row of text. I would like it to stay fixed on the top right of the panel.

Here is how the HTML look like:

```
<!-- childeren -->
<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-info fadein fadeout" ng-repeat="p in panels">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#test_{{p}}" style="cursor:pointer">
            <h4 class="panel-title"> 
              open / close - test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test - {{p}}
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="close(p, $event)"></span>
            </h4>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute` on closing button and `position:relative` on the parent.

```
.panel-title {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 20px; // add padding right so text doesn't overlap on button
}

.panel-title > glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give following css will work for you.

```
.glyphicon{
  position: absolute !important;
  right: 1px;
}

.panel-info > .panel-heading {
  position: relative ;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vt7tuj8b/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

[working try this code](https://jsfiddle.net/vt7tuj8b/5/)

put `span` tag first with class `pull right`

```
<h4 class="panel-title">
     <span class="glyphicon pull-right glyphicon-remove topright" ng-click="close(p, $event)"></span>
     open / close - test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test - {{p}}

                </h4>
```